# Pathological example to extension of measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Even tough it is true that in canonical spaces one can extend a compatible family of measures this is not true in general. See for instance  Ikeda and Watanabe (Stochastic Differential equations and Diffusion processes)

[image]

Do you know an example of when such an extension fails to exist?